Add custom color to both light and dark mode in bulma
Bulma 1.0 added support for dark mode.
I already figured out how to add a custom color to Bulma.
Now, I want to know how I can get it to use a different color value in dark mode.
$groovy: #4298B8; 
// dark mode #286B86;

$custom-colors: (
        'groovy': $groovy
);

@use "bulma/sass" with (
  $custom-colors: $custom-colors,
);

What I want to achieve is that groovy uses #4298B8 for light mode and #286B86 for dark mode.
